# Are Rails Tests Functions really Important / Useful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I'm reading the book Agile Web Development with Rails and most of the times, I skip the testing parts. I hate doing testing like this, I'm not sure why and it just feel weird to write tests codes like that. Giving that I don't fully understand how the testing really works in rails. And the test reporting just doesn't impress me so far.

So, how important is it to follow / use the build in test?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you dislike about testing in Rails? What would you prefer? What about the reporting fails to impress you?

Comment: Possible copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844220/rails-3-too-many-ways-to-test

Comment: Take a look at the video series I mention [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987128/ror-testing-framework-for-rails-3/5987187#5987187). I think if you put just a little effort, and follow that video series as a start, you will come to love testing. Also, when you look for a RoR job, and you mention that you don't/like test, it's very probable that you won't get hired!

Comment: @hammar: let's redefine that I don't hate testing in Rails :) I never done something like this before, normally we do testing manually all the time (going through pages and filling out forms). That sounds more natural for now.

Comment: @Zabba, thanks for the link!! gonna finish the book first.

Comment: @Phelios: There are many benefits to using automated testing. It enables you to test more often, and to be more consistent. That said, there are cases where it might be too hard or even impossible to automate your tests, but when they are feasible, automated tests are usually well worth the investment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really important. In Rails especially, testing is an integrated part of development and this is one of the things that makes Rails an Enterprise solution. Testing is a great way to make sure that your code behaves the way you expect it to behave. You may not understand why it's important now, but you will definitely see the benefits when refactoring your code, or a weird bug comes up.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic languages give you far too many ways to shoot yourself in the foot.  Ruby is no exception.  Test, test, and test again.